# Why is my s3 createPresignedPost not respecting the content-range-length condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to post a file to s3 using createPresignedPost. The file is posting to my bucket but it is not respecting the file size constraint. Here is my code and the file upload is base64 encoded string.

```
function postObjectSignedUrl(req) {
const key = `${req + "/" + uuid.v4()}`;
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'base',
        Expires: 60 * 60, // in seconds,
        Fields: {
            key: key,
        },
        conditions: [
            ['content-length-range', 0,1000000]
        ]


    }
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    })
})
```

}

My client side code is the following:

```
var data = new FormData();
const getUrl = await getSignedUrl();
const keys = getUrl["fields"];
$.each(keys, function(key,value){
    data.append(key,value);
});


data.append("file", profilePic);
try {

    const result = await fetch(getUrl["url"], {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: data
    })
    if (result.status === 204){

    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err, " error ")
}
```

Comment: What is the size of your tests or why you say it is not working? Remember the size is in Bytes and the limit in your code is 0.953674316 MiB or 1 MB.

Comment: true I am working with 2MB and it is not throwing any error it just uploads

Comment: The attribute is Conditions not conditions. I think It is the issue.

Comment: Interesting hector, Please answer the question so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: great! I have posted my answer. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally params attributes in NodeJS SDK are Upper Camel Case so you have to change "conditions" for "Conditions".

BTW you can change your url generator code as follow :)

```
function postObjectSignedUrl(req) {
    const key = `${req + "/" + uuid.v4()}`;

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'base',
        Expires: 60 * 60, // in seconds,
        Fields: {
            key: key,
        },
        Conditions: [
            ['content-length-range', 0,1000000]
        ]
    }

    return s3.createPresignedPost(params).promise();
})
```

Regards,